# add_action where function has arguments

Tags: actions

I have a general question about functions and add_action to it.

I have a function and adding an action do it. But how can i define a value for the argument on this action?

```
add_action( 'um_members_just_after_name', 'my_members_after_user_name', 10, 1 );
function my_members_after_user_name( $user_id ) {

    // how can i set a value for $user_id ???

    echo '<i class="um-verified um-icon-checkmark-circled um-tip-s"></i>';
}
```

Sorry, it may be a stupid question but i dont get the point for it... Normally in php it looks like this and i understand it here

```
function Multiplication($x, $y) {
    $z = $x * $y;
    return $z;
}
     echo "5 * 10 = " . Multiplication(5, 10) . "<br>";
     echo "7 * 13 = " . Multiplication(7, 13) . "<br>";
     echo "2 * 4 = " . Multiplication(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress core and third-party plugins can trigger events during the execution of their respective code. When you call `add_action` on `um_members_just_after_name`, you're saying: Whenever this `um_members_just_after_name` action runs, go ahead and run my function `my_members_after_user_name`, too. That said, `$user_id` must be supplied by `um_members_just_after_name`, in other words, if `um_members_just_after_name` doesn't exist or doesn't supply `$user_id`, it will never be set-- it's not something you can set unless you are the creator of the `um_members_just_after_name` action.

Comment: Thanks for explanation... So i can say, if $user_id = 2 then do the action?

Comment: No, it's not something you can set. It would already need to be passed in by the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what NightHawk posted, actions do not normally allow you to change the value of the parameter passed to it, but filters do. [Read more about actions and filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) in WordPress.

I think it might be helpful to talk about the other side of [`add_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) which is [`do_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/).

### Do and Add Action

For actions, a `do_action` is added to code in a plugin or in WordPress core to allow you to run your own function at particular points in the process. Developers usually refer to this as a hook since you're hooking into a process you normally wouldn't have access to.

You use `add_action` to tell that `do_action` that you'd like it to run your function.

### Priority

The `10` in your code specifies the order in which it should run compared to other places where `add_action` is using that same `do_action` hook.

### Number of Parameters

The final parameter (`1` in your code) specifies the number of parameters you're expecting. This number cannot be more than the number of parameters in `do_action`. 
For example, `do_action( 'um_members_just_after_name', $user_id );` will only ever pass over `$user_id` no matter how many parameters you want. On the other hand, `do_action( 'um_members_just_after_name', $user_id, $user, $id );` will pass over 3 parameters, so you can specify 1, 2, or 3 and have those available in your function.

**Note:** the `do_action` must specify these parameters are available for you to make use of them in your function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to fire this action for certain user or users.
 Try this

```
add_action( 'um_members_just_after_name', 'my_members_after_user_name', 10, 1 );
function my_members_after_user_name( $user_id ) {

    // how can i set a value for $user_id ???
    $user_ids =array(120, 220, 320, 420); // set values here
    if ( in_array($user_id, $user_ids ) ){


       // do something here

       echo '<i class="um-verified um-icon-checkmark-circled um-tip-s"></i>';
     }

}
```

I hope this helps.